# Redux-thunk not dispatching actions

Tags: redux, jsx, redux-thunk

I have a a pair of Redux actions that I want to dispatch when a button is pressed. One of these should take a list of services and perform reducer logic on it, and the other should just trigger some logic in the reducer:

```jsx
function retrieveServices(services) {
    return {
        type: RETRIEVE_SERVICES,
        services,
    };
}

function toggleSubmitState() {
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_SUBMIT_STATE,
    };
}
```

I have the following action that I assumed would do the trick:

```jsx
export function submitGameplan(services) {
    return (dispatch => {
        dispatch(toggleSubmitState());
        dispatch(retrieveServices(services));
    };
}
```

This is how I call it in my component:

```jsx
    const { submitter, dispatch, services } = this.props;

    const submitWithServices = () => {
        dispatch(submitter(services));
    };

    return (
      <div>

        <button onClick={submitWithServices}>
            <div>Submit</div>
        </button>

      </div>
    );
```

where the `submitter` action being passed in is `submitGameplan`.

Although redux-thunk seems to be picking up the action and firing it (I'm getting console.log output), it's not dispatching the actions.

Aside from the (likely) possibility that I am mis-calling the function in my action, perhaps there is some issue with the fact that I have done this in my main App-level component:

```jsx
const boundActions = bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
```

and then passed all actions as `boundActions`, so i.e. my component would get `boundActions.submitGameplan`.

Still, I'm not certain why this action wouldn't dispatch either of the two actions as written.

Comment: Are you actually the redux-thunk middleware? Ie what does your store initialization look like?

What do you mean that you are getting console.log output? From redux-logger?

Comment: I don't be dispatching your thunk action. Just call it like any function - which it is. Your submitter (SubmitGamePlan) is not dispatching anything to your reducer but are rather creating actions that are themselves dispatching to the reducer.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this worked after a recompile, no idea why it didn't work before.